# Very simple Wordpress + jquery tools issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scrollable

I'm have a real tough time getting this working. Any help will be repaid with lottery winning karma :-)

I've installed a vanilla WP site and only edited one post and the functions.php to add the CSS. This demonstrates the problem.

Nothing was working when I added all the jquery/tools wp_register_script/wp_enqueue_script declarations in functions.php so for the sake of sanity and temporarily, they are in the post (I know this isn't the correct place).

So, this nearly works. I get no errors, but the page (which works fine without WP) doesn't render the contents of the panels. Any ideas? Looking at Chrome console, all the resources are loaded, all there scripts are there.

http://crystal-globe.com/jqt/

Thanks for any help. Hair is being pulled out...

Comment: why don't you add the CSS and JQuery includes in the header opposed to the functions file ?

Comment: I've read that the functions is where all the includes should be. I have actually tried *a lot* of things, this is the most functional version. When I can get it working I will (slowly) put it all where it should go.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you shouldn't be adding code to the functions.php file that are not directly related to your wordpress configuration (like custom post types and functions for php).

Revert your functions.php file and any extra code you've added to your files; then try:

Find header.php and between the `<head> </head>` tags include the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); wp_head(); ?>
```

as a simple test to see if jQuery is working in the header;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".scrollable").scrollable();
});
</script>
```

In the header add the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
/*
    root element for the scrollable.
    when scrolling occurs this element stays still.
*/
.scrollable {

    /* required settings */
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 660px;
    height:90px;
}

/*
    root element for scrollable items. Must be absolutely positioned
    and it should have a extremely large width to accommodate scrollable items.
    it's enough that you set width and height for the root element and
    not for this element.
*/
.scrollable .items {
    /* this cannot be too large */
    width:20000em;
    position:absolute;
}

/*
    a single item. must be floated in horizontal scrolling.
    typically, this element is the one that *you* will style
    the most.
*/
.items div {
    float:left;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Ok, so I've added that code to the header and reverted functions to the vanilla. jQuery is working fine, but now I'm not finding scrollable from the jquery.tools library. I've added  <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script> under your jquery include which is obviously getting pulled in.

Comment: ok, see the above answer try adding that to your header now, make sure the html is getting displayed on the home page too, but i believe that already is.  Just add the CSS and change the original script you added.

Comment: Added your changes PLUS included the css from the jquery.tools plugin. Now we have the same problem. Everything looks to be working except all the content doesn't get rendered, even though it's present when you look at the DOM with Chrome. Very odd. I can literally cut-n-paste this into a blank HTML doc and it works fine. There must be lots of people out there using jquery.tools with WordPress.

Comment: css style sheet is adding default styles "display:none;" from the one you included.

Comment: The style sheet is the standard one from the jquery tools site. This is why I am so confused. If I cut-n-paste all this code into a non-WP page it all starts working, no problem. I can understand if scripts and styles are being included in the wrong order, but this is like something in WP is tripping the library or CSS up. I'll keep trying. Today is turning into a marathon :-)